# Refresh page in Angular. Socket.io issue

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs

I my chat web app i use socket.io with RxJS; to have "persistent" socket i create socket.io client in the service constructor; everything is ok, but if the user refreshes (F5 / Cmd-R) the app, client socket is recreated and the old one is destroyed.
Is there a way to avoid it, maintaining the same socket.io client?

Comment: Short answer is no. It's gonna create a new instance everytime when u refresh the page. What you can do if you are using an auth system u can hold the data on user's object?

Comment: Have you considered IndexedDB ?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever page is refreshed, all the memory this page consumed is removed, so the context is lost and all the object instances also
That's why there is no way to persist socket client instance on refresh.
If you want to somehow track the same user accross the browser session, you could genetate some unique Id on the first time persist it to [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) 
And then pass it to the [query parameter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#with-query-parameters) on socket initialization. And by that id, you will be able to identify this user across the browser session